# Can anyone help identify a book-on-tape learning program from the 80s about monsters?

Tags: story-identification, audio-book

Does anyone remember a book-on-tape learning program from the 80s (that's when I had it anyway), that was based on maybe a haunted castle or something, and everyone in it was a monster?  I thought the name was something like "Creature Teacher" or similar?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.